# math.Random isn't working right

Tags: java, math, random

I'm trying to simulate a coin flip using the code below.

```
public class Coin
{
    public static double result;
        int[] count = new count[2];

    public static void flip()
    {       
        result = Math.random();
    }

        public static boolean isHeads()
        {
        if (result == 0.0)
        {
                    count[0]++;
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
                    count[1]++;
            return true;
        }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             flip();
             isHeads();
             System.out.println(count[0]);
             System.out.println(count[1]);
        }
}
```

For some reason Eclipse says that the

import java.util.Random;

is never used even though I'm clearly using it. I didn't put my for loop into the code above but it loops n number of times and then outputs the result. No matter how many times it loops it always returns that the result is greater than 0.0 which can't be right. Am I calling Math.random incorrectly?

Comment: Math.Random and java.util.Random are not the same thing!

Comment: They are different things, Eclipse is right.

Comment: `result == 0.0` is far less likely than I think you think it is.

Comment: What is the issue? The warning or the "result is always greater then 0.0"? The probability of getting a random to be 0.0 is very slim in double arithmetics, and is 0 in real numbers arithmetics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll recomend using

`java.util.Random`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int headCount = 0;
    int tailCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int value = rand.nextInt(2);

        if (value == 0) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            headCount++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tailCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Head Count: " + headCount);
    System.out.println("Tail Count: " + tailCount);

}
```

Comment: If you have `value = rand.nextInt(2);`, you know that `value` is either 0 or 1. The test `value % 2 == 0` is then unnecessarily complicated, `value == 0` is clearer.

Comment: Why do you have to use .nextInt() ? Why won't .nextDouble() work?

Comment: Both will work, is just a matter of creating a 50-50 chance of getting certain value to simulate a flip coin.

Comment: When I used .nextDouble() I always get tails and when I use .nextInt() my results are resemble a 50/50 probability.

Answer (score 9):

You are using Math and it may be using Random, but you are not using Random anywhere.

> No matter how many times it loops it always returns that the result is greater than 0.0 which can't be right. Am I calling Math.random incorrectly?

There is 2 ^ 53 possible values between 0.0 and 1.0 and as Random only uses a 48-bit seed, it is possible you could generate every `double` it will create and no one value ever occurs. If you use SecureRandom, you have a one in 2 ^ 53 chance of returning 0.0.

Answer (score 3):

Once you fix your compile issue, you'll discover that your "coin" is not fair: it gives you "tails" a lot more often than "heads". In fact, you'd rarely get any "heads" at all!

This is because `random()` gives you a `double` between `0` and `1`, not an `int` of `0` and `1`. Therefore you need to change your condition as follows:

```
if (result < 0.5) {
    count[0]++;
    return false;
} else {
    count[1]++;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is far more helpful than the initial answers.

Answer (score 2):

Math.Random and java.util.Random are two different things.

```
static Random random = new Math.Random();
public static void flip()  {       
    result = random.nextDouble();
}
```

and

```
 public static boolean isHeads() {
    if (result > 0.5) {
       count[0]++;
       return false;
    }
    //else {
        count[1]++;
        return true;
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an instance of [util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and use it to generate your numbers.

You could replace

```
public static void flip()
{       
    result = Math.random();
}
```

by

```
static Random r = new Math.Random();
public static void flip()  {       
    result = r.nextDouble();
}
```

And as what you need is in fact a boolean, I'd suggest you use the [nextBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean%28%29) method :

```
static Random r = new Math.Random();
static boolean result;
public static void flip()  {       
    result = r.nextBoolean();
}
public static boolean isHeads() {
    count[result?1:0]++;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "create an instance of `Math.Random`" - did you mean `util.Random`?

Comment: it's not Math.Random, dystroy ;)

Comment: Math of java does have a random() method, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` is a method in `java.lang.Math` class

Comment: Maybe "random", not "Random" ?